# how to shorten your code which refers to other functions

Tags: r, optimization

Let's consider very simple function following :

```
stats <- function(x, method) {
  if (method == "mean") {
    mean(x)
  } else if (method == "median") {
    median(x)
  } else if (method == "diff") diff(x)
}
```

Notice that each function has same name as method (mean-mean, median-median, diff-diff). My question is : Is there any way how can I change method (as character) to function ? So intuitively what I want to have is

```
stats <- function(x, method) {
  method(x)
}
```

It can shorten a very big codes for which a lot of things are done identically.

Do you have idea how it can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try your function? It actually works.

```
stats <- function(x, method) {
  method(x)
}

stats(1:10, sum)
#[1] 55
stats(1:10, mean)
#[1] 5.5
stats(1:10, diff)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

---

If you want to have a function to accept character values of the function name you can use `match.fun`.

```
stats <- function(x, method) {
  match.fun(method)(x)
}
stats(1:10, "sum")
#[1] 55
```

Comment: Yes, but you provided sum,mean and diff without quotation marks so that's the reason why it's working :D

Comment: @John Check update answer to make it work with quotation marks.

Comment: Exactly! match.fun is what I was seeking for! Thanks ;))